# How much overhang is acceptable on 1/2” drywall?

Tags: drywall

I am installing some 1/2” drywall over 1/4” paneling. On one end of the wall there is no stud to attach to because of a cabinet. The drywall will run wild for 5”. Is this ok or should I install a cripple 2x4 at the edge of the cabinet?

Comment: How will the end be finished?  Just tape and mud or maybe moulding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.